# How to use LLVM-C to JIT-compile the floating-point identity function

Tags: c, llvm, x86-64, jit

So far I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <llvm-c/Analysis.h>
#include <llvm-c/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm-c/Target.h>
#include <llvm-c/Transforms/Scalar.h>


int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{ 
  char *error = NULL;
  LLVMLinkInMCJIT();
  LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();
  LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter();
  LLVMInitializeNativeAsmParser();

  LLVMModuleRef mod = LLVMModuleCreateWithName("minimal_module");
  LLVMTypeRef identity_args[] = { LLVMDoubleType(), NULL };
  LLVMValueRef identity = LLVMAddFunction(mod, "identity", LLVMFunctionType(LLVMDoubleType(), identity_args, 1, 0));
  LLVMSetFunctionCallConv(identity, LLVMCCallConv);
  LLVMValueRef n = LLVMGetParam(identity, 0);

  LLVMBasicBlockRef entry = LLVMAppendBasicBlock(identity, "entry");
  LLVMBuilderRef builder = LLVMCreateBuilder();
  LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, entry);
  LLVMBuildRet(builder, n);

  LLVMVerifyModule(mod, LLVMAbortProcessAction, &error);
  LLVMDisposeMessage(error);

  LLVMExecutionEngineRef engine;
  error = NULL;
  if(LLVMCreateJITCompilerForModule(&engine, mod, 2, &error) != 0) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
    LLVMDisposeMessage(error);
    abort();
  } 

  LLVMDumpModule(mod);

  LLVMGenericValueRef exec_args[] = {LLVMCreateGenericValueOfFloat(LLVMDoubleType(), 1.25)};
  LLVMGenericValueRef exec_res = LLVMRunFunction(engine, identity, 1, exec_args);
  fprintf(stderr, "\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "; Running identity(%f) with JIT...\n", 1.25);
  fprintf(stderr, "; Result: %f\n", LLVMGenericValueToFloat(LLVMDoubleType(), exec_res));

  LLVMRemoveModule(engine, mod, &mod, &error);
  LLVMDisposeModule(mod);
  LLVMDisposeExecutionEngine(engine);
  LLVMDisposeBuilder(builder);
  return 0;
}
```

The corresponding implementation using 32-bit integers works, i.e. `identity(42)` will return `42`. However the floating-point version above returns 0.0. Above program generates the following output:

```
; ModuleID = 'minimal_module'
source_filename = "minimal_module"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"

define double @identity(double) {
entry:
  ret double %0
}

; Running identity(1.250000) with JIT...
; Result: 0.000000
```

I am using LLVM-3.9 under Debian Jessie on an AMD computer. My question is: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem.
Instead of using `LLVMRunFunction` one can use `LLVMGetFunctionAddress` to get the address of the function and call it directly using C (or using an FFI library).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <llvm-c/Analysis.h>
#include <llvm-c/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm-c/Target.h>
#include <llvm-c/Transforms/Scalar.h>


int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char *error = NULL;
  LLVMLinkInMCJIT();
  LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();
  LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter();
  LLVMInitializeNativeAsmParser();

  LLVMModuleRef mod = LLVMModuleCreateWithName("minimal_module");
  LLVMTypeRef identity_args[] = { LLVMInt32Type() };
  LLVMValueRef identity = LLVMAddFunction(mod, "identity", LLVMFunctionType(LLVMInt32Type(), identity_args, 1, 0));
  LLVMSetFunctionCallConv(identity, LLVMCCallConv);
  LLVMValueRef n = LLVMGetParam(identity, 0);

  LLVMBasicBlockRef entry = LLVMAppendBasicBlock(identity, "entry");
  LLVMBuilderRef builder = LLVMCreateBuilder();
  LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, entry);
  LLVMBuildRet(builder, n);

  LLVMVerifyModule(mod, LLVMAbortProcessAction, &error);
  LLVMDisposeMessage(error);

  LLVMExecutionEngineRef engine;
  error = NULL;
  if(LLVMCreateJITCompilerForModule(&engine, mod, 2, &error) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
    LLVMDisposeMessage(error);
    abort();
  }
  int (*fun)(int) = (int (*)(int))LLVMGetFunctionAddress(engine, "identity");

  LLVMDumpModule(mod);

  fprintf(stderr, "\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "; Running identity(42) with JIT...\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "; Result: %d\n", (*fun)(42));

  LLVMRemoveModule(engine, mod, &mod, &error);
  LLVMDisposeModule(mod);
  LLVMDisposeExecutionEngine(engine);
  LLVMDisposeBuilder(builder);
  return 0;
}
```